# desactivar domingos en el input date html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

necesito desactivar los domingos del input date , es decir que el usuario no pueda elegir los domingos,lo mejor seria que me bloquee esos dias,es decir no quiero que me diga usted eligio un dia invalido , si no que no aparesca el domingo 
parecido a esta imagen que lo saque de internet
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ahi me desactiva los fin de semana yo solo quiero el domingo gracias

el codigo que tengo es solo del input, no uso nigun plugin

```
 <label>Feche inicio</label>
 <input id="infechaini" 
     type="date" name="infechaini" 
     onblur="obtenerfechafinf1();" style="height:30px;">
```

Comment: Utilizas algún plugin? si es así que plugin utilizas? y coloca tu código en la pregunta de como tienes configurado, recuerda añadir un [mcve]

Comment: Los input nativo de los browsers no permiten deshabilitar un día por semana, si podrías deshabilitar un rango de fechas pero un solamente un día no.

Tenés 2 opciones: Usar un plugin (buena opción) o validar después de elegir el día.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de concepto usando un `SUBMIT` falso escondido para disparar la validación del `FORM` que engloba al `INPUT` a testear si es domingo.

> vanilla Javascript. mensaje personalizado. adapte a sus necesidades. referencias al pie

```js
var elDate = document.getElementById('infechaini');
var elForm = document.getElementById('elForm');
var elSubmit = document.getElementById('elSubmit');

function sinDomingos(){
    var day = new Date(elDate.value ).getUTCDay();
    // Días 0-6, 0 es Domingo 6 es Sábado
    elDate.setCustomValidity(''); // limpiarlo para evitar pisar el fecha inválida
    if( day == 0 ){
       elDate.setCustomValidity('Domingos no disponibles, por favor seleccione otro día');
    } else {
       elDate.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    if(!elForm.checkValidity()) {elSubmit.click()};
}

function obtenerfechafinf1(){
    sinDomingos();
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="elForm">
  <label>Feche inicio</label>
  <input 
   id="infechaini" 
   type="date" name="infechaini" onChange="sinDomingos();" 
   onblur="obtenerfechafinf1();" style="height:30px;" required="required"/>
   <input
    id="elSubmit" type="submit" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

Referencias:

** https://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/

** https://stackoverflow.com/q/26096847/1423096

Tablas de compatibilidad del `<INPUT type="date">` :

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date#Compatibilidad_entre_navegadores

Ejemplos de UI en los distintos navegadores que lo soportan:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date

Nota: edge muestra el UI de una forma que no es posible saber que día de la semana es.

Can I use link (puedo usarlo?)

https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date

Comment: Hola, la respuesta funciona bien en Chrome, pero no funciona en Mozilla y tal vez tampoco en otros navegadores, es algo a tomar en cuenta, saludos.

Comment: editado, links para saber que navegadores soportan el control

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el siguiente script.
Necesitas usar jquery y jquery-ui

```
$("#infechaini").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0), ''];
} });
```

Comment: El OP no hace uso de alguna librería o plugin, y por lo que veo no solicita el uso de alguna. Considera eliminar esta respuesta ya que no responde a la pregunta, solo es una sugerencia para usar alguna libreria